# How to create a progress bar with two colors in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

I need to create a progress bar in iOS where for first 90% it is in white color and rest 10% red. I have checked many codes available online.

I need to have a simple code for this simple progress bar.

Can anybody guide me.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uiprogressbar   may this help u ....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to do it yourself:

1. Create a view with red background. Assume width is 100 px.
2. Create a view with white background above red view.
3. To show progress increase width of white view. 1% = 1px

If you want width more then 100 px then your progress will be in width ratio. 
For example

1. 320px width: 3.2px = 1%
2. 1080px width: 20.16px = 2%

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple

First create two view, one is background view & another is progress Bar view 
Now, put red view as subview of your progress view and make it `clipsToBounds = YES`

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 50)];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

CGRect rctProgreccBar = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 30);
UIView *progressView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rctProgreccBar];
progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
progressView.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280-28, 0, 28, 30)];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[progressView addSubview:redView];
[backView addSubview:progressView];

[self.view addSubview:backView];
```

Now you can just increase or decries the process bar with updating it's frame's width value.

```
rctProgreccBar.size.width = 56; //for 20%
progressView.frame = rctProgreccBar;
```

**Note:** You can also set size as per your screen resolution dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to display progress bar

```
@interface ViewController () {

    UIView *progressBarView;
    UIView *progressBgView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Pass the frame where you want to display progress bar
    [self addProgressView:CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 30)];

    // Apply colors
    [self setProgressBgColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setProgressBarColor:[UIColor greenColor]];


    // Pass progress percent value here
    [self setPercentage:80];
}

#pragma mark - Progress methods

- (void)addProgressView:(CGRect)progressFrame {

    UIView *progressView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:progressFrame];

    //Progress background view
    progressBgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, progressView.frame.size.width-10, progressView.frame.size.height-10)];
    progressBgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    progressBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

    //Progress animation view
    progressBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, progressBgView.frame.size.height)];
    progressBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    progressBarView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

   [progressBgView addSubview:progressBarView];
   [progressView addSubview:progressBgView];
   [self.view addSubview:progressView];
}

- (void)setPercentage:(int)percentage {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        [progressBarView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,(progressBgView.frame.size.width*percentage)/100,progressBgView.frame.size.height)];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

 - (void)setProgressBgColor:(UIColor *)color {

    progressBgView.backgroundColor = color;
 }

 - (void)setProgressBarColor:(UIColor *)color {

    progressBarView.backgroundColor = color;
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution with using views:

interface:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    UIView *progressBarOverView;
    UIView *progressBarLine;
    int progressBarPadding;
    NSTimer *progressBarTimer;
    int progressBarPercent;
}
```

declare:

```
@implementation TableViewController
//set timer progress
-(void)setProgressPercent:(int)percent{
    percent = percent > 100 ? 100 : percent;
    float size = (progressBarOverView.frame.size.width - progressBarPadding*2)/100*percent;
    CGRect frame = progressBarLine.frame;
    frame.size.width = size;
    progressBarLine.frame = frame;

    if (percent > 99) {
        [progressBarTimer invalidate];
    }
}

//action to update progress bar timer
-(IBAction)updateTimerToPercent:(id)sender{
    [self setProgressPercent:progressBarPercent+=1];
}


//initialize progress bar
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //init varibbles
    progressBarPadding = 5;
    progressBarPercent = 0;

    //init over view
    progressBarOverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 40)];
    progressBarOverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //init bar line view
    progressBarLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(progressBarPadding, progressBarPadding, 0, progressBarOverView.frame.size.height - progressBarPadding*2)];
    progressBarLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    //set subviews
    [progressBarOverView addSubview:progressBarLine];
    [self.view addSubview:progressBarOverView];

    //set timer value
    [self setProgressPercent:progressBarPercent];

    //create timer to automaticaly update timer
    progressBarTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(updateTimerToPercent:)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];

}
@end
```

Better way is use component UIPRogressView :D